# Send a Google Analytics event when a specific text string is present on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, dom-events

I have somewhere on website a specific text, let's say "NewYork", and I want to fire a Google Analytics event to track all the occurrences of this string.

For example if a visitor come to a webpage that contain the string 'NewYork', I want to send a Google Analytics event.

Text string is in a span tag as `<span class="city">NewYork</span>`

I do not know any JavaScript codes, just tried the following code adapted from someone else. And it is not working at all.

```js
<script>
var htmlString = $('body').html().toString();
var index = htmlString.indexOf("NewYork");

if (index != -1)
   { ga('send', 'event', 'yesNewYork', 'foundnewyork');   } </script>
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Possibly a jQuery solution?

Comment: The code looks fine although you could make it a little more specific using `var htmlString = $('.city').text()`. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Tested above code. GA event is not fired . '<script>
var htmlString = $('.city').text();
var index = htmlString.indexOf("NewYork");
if (index != -1)
   { ga('send', 'event', 'yesNewYork', 'foundnewyork');   } </script>'

Comment: Would be a good idea to put this into a document.ready()-call to make sure the text is actually rendered when you check for your string.

Comment: @EikePierstorff could you please provide an example? Sorry, I do not know how to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct in principle, but can be improved upon.

You are already using jQuery syntax so I just assume jQuery is available.

First I would suggest you follow Lars Graubner suggestion and select a more specific element and grab the text content instead of the html (as the name suggests the text()-function does not return HTML markup but text only).

```
$('.city').text()
```

will adress the span from your example - the dot in the selector says "Look for elements with a classname of".

This will actually return all elements that have the class, but for your use case that does not matter much.

However you must make sure that the text is actually rendered on the page before you call your jQuery selector; if you place it in the head of the page the text isn't there yet when the event tracking runs and thus your selector will return nothing.

You can either put the script in the footer of the page, or you can wrap it into jQuery's document.ready-call. This makes sure that the function only runs after the DOM of the document has rendered (meaning that the page structure is complete, event if images and other assets are not yet loaded. Text will be present at this point). So this would look like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var myString = $('.city').text();
   if(myString.indexof('NewYork') > -1) {
      ga('send', 'event', 'yesNewYork', 'foundnewyork'); 
   }
});
```

(Obviously this assumes you have jQuery included).

If this still doesn't work you need to be more specific as to the actual error your are getting.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have tested your code as adviced. However still the Google Analytics event is not fired when the page is viewed. I have setup this page for testing [ http://imtoolsclub.com/ga-event-test.html ] . In the console there is an error 'Uncaught TypeError: myString.indexof is not a function' . Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: This should be "indexOf" (capital "O"), sorry.

Comment: Excellent! this code work. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just a note, when UA code is implemented via GTM, this code doesn't work. There is an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined' . Few people have suggested it is a problem of using GTM.

Comment: This is not exactly a "problem". GTM creates a randomly named instance of the javascript tracker, so calls to the default will fail. You can fix this by setting a tracker name in the advanced configuration of your ga tag (or simply check "use named tracker" and leave the field empty, this should set the name to the default).

Comment: Eike I have tested setting the name tracker in GTM, and still event was not fired. However, I have switched back to using GA code withing the CMS instead using GTM, Together with your code problem is solved now. Thank you for your kind support :)